# py2app ImportError: No module named sip

Tags: python, py2app

I have already create an [issue](https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/330) in github. But no one reply.

The question is:

I run`python3 setup.py py2app` and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/th/source/duomai/send_email.py/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 925, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1147, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1244, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1099, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/recipes/sip.py", line 111, in check
    mf.import_hook("sip", m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1114, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1215, in _find_head_package
    raise ImportError("No module named " + qname)
ImportError: No module named sip
```

And my setup.py

```py
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['cli.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

It's seems like qt relative. But I didn't used qt, I just use the tkinter...

The detail log is long, I create an attach. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pcc9zv7dgoq37j/log.txt?dl=0

How to fix this?

Comment: did you install the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, If I run `python3 cli.py`. It can start normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the packages to your options in the setup file, like this:

```
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages':['tkinter']}
```